# Using batch script to automatically copy latest file to folder

Tags: windows, cmd, batch-file

I would like to call for help on my attempt to create a script which will automatically check last modified file and transfer it to destination.

What I have is this:

```
@Echo Off
Set _Delay=1
for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims==" %%a in (config.ini) do (
if %%a==source set _Monitor=%%b
if %%a==destination set _Dest=%%b
if %%a==timer set _Timer=%%b
)
Set _Base=%temp%\BaselineState.dir
Set _Chck=%temp%\ChkState.dir
Set _OS=6
Ver|Findstr /I /C:"Version 5">Nul
If %Errorlevel%==0 Set _OS=5 & Set /A _Delay=_Delay*1000
Goto :_Xfer
:_StartMon
@echo off
SET R1=Start /w Sync1.vbs
Call :_SetBaseline "%_Base%" "%_Monitor%"
:_MonLoop
If %_OS%==5 (Ping 1.0.0.0 -n 1 -w %_Delay%>Nul) Else Timeout %_Delay%>Nul
Call :_SetBaseline "%_Chck%" "%_Monitor%"
FC /A /L "%_Base%" "%_Chck%">Nul
If %ErrorLevel%==0 Goto _MonLoop
::
for /l %%a in (%_Timer%,-1,0) do (
@Echo::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
@Echo:: SEC Auto Transfer ::
@Echo:: Aizal 16 June 2012 ::
@Echo::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
@Echo This script will scan SEC Data Folder for
@Echo new files every 30 minutes and will copy
@Echo it to the Server. Make sure you set correct
@Echo folder before using this script.
ECHO.
ECHO Currently recording:
FOR /F %%a in ('xcopy "%_Monitor%\*.SEC" "%_Dest%" /L /Y') DO (
IF NOT EXIST "%_Dest%.\%%~nxa" ECHO %%~nxa
)
ECHO Refreshing...
ECHO Please wait %%a seconds...
%R1%
cls
)
::
:_Xfer
FOR /F %%a in ('xcopy "%_Monitor%\*.SEC" "%_Dest%" /L /Y') DO (
IF NOT EXIST "%_Dest%.\%%~nxa" xcopy "%%a" "%_Dest%" /Y
)
::
Echo.Change Detected
ECHO.
Goto :_StartMon
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Subroutine
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:_SetBaseline
If Exist "%temp%\tempfmstate.dir" Del "%temp%\tempfmstate.dir"
For /F "Tokens=* Delims=" %%I In ('Dir /S "%~2"') Do (
Set _Last=%%I
>>"%temp%\tempfmstate.dir" Echo.%%I
)
>"%~1" Findstr /V /C:"%_Last%" "%temp%\tempfmstate.dir"
Goto :EOF
```

Now, if you noticed the script will compare the content of source folder with the content of the destination folder and will copy the files from source if there is not already file in destination. I would like to know if someone can help me figuring out how to make the script to check the last modified file in source folder and ONLY copy it to the destination AND if the said file is currently in use/being write to then script will wait until it finished before trying to copy it again.

Also, right now I have to edit source.ini file to specify which folder I want to monitor and each time I have to change the subfolder path to watch for changes, is there a way to watch parent folder for any new files and take that file to the destination?

I found this script on the net but hoping to check the file not based on day but instead of time.

```
::Copy Files Made Or Modified Today
@echo off
setlocal
set source= <source directory>
set dest= <destination directory>
pushd "%source%"
set t=%date:~4%
::for /f %%a in ('dir /b /a-d /o-d') do call :PROCESS "%%a"
goto :eof
popd
:PROCESS
for /f %%j in ('echo %~t1') do set d=%%j
if "%d%"=="%t%" copy %1 "%dest%"
goto :eof
```

Hope to find the solution from here.

Many thanks

Comment: Considered robocopy? it supports monitoring, mirroring & retries from the command line

Comment: I know xcopy is obsolete but I'm sure it still can be done? no?

Comment: You can download the xp version from the xp resource kit

Comment: Oh, yes..I spoke too soon. I do have robocopy since it's XP. Still, haven't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

With this you'll get the last modified file:

```
for /f %%A in ('dir /b /tw /o-d not-mandatory-file-mask') do (
   set last_file=%%A
   goto :endloop
)
:endloop
```

With this you'll copy the file if it is possible. If not it will try again and again:

```
:tryagain
set /a errorlevel=0
copy some_dir\%last_file% %destination%
if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 (
   sleep 10
   goto :tryagain
) else (
   goto :end
)
:end
```